# React: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, express, axios

i am getting the error

```
Grade.jsx:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Grade.jsx:52:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Grade (Grade.jsx:39:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
(anonymous) @ Grade.jsx:52
Grade @ Grade.jsx:39
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26096
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:25651
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Grade> component:

    at Grade (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6687:56)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:277704:5)
    at Outlet (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:278056:26)
    at div
    at StudentProfileLayout (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6946:72)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:277704:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:278141:5)
    at Routing
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:349:78)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:278079:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:276396:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

but if i comment out the grade column value before the Grade comp renders,there will be no error.it will display all the columns with there values after that if i uncomment out it displays the grade column values properly.
but without commenting out the values of the grade column,the error happens
please i need help guys,help.
the server responds with this values

```
ayne abreham alemayehu
new ObjectId("63efb168503e390f0b7c986a")
new ObjectId("63efb168503e390f0b7c986a")
[
  {
    gd: {
      _id: new ObjectId("63f16c7f03e5a86d748ab2c4"),
      batch: 1,
      department: 'None',
      stream: 'None',
      subject: 'b',
      class: new ObjectId("63efb168503e390f0b7c986a"),
      grades: [Array],
      createdAt: 2023-02-19T00:25:35.272Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-02-19T00:25:35.272Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    sem: 1
  },
  {
    gd: {
      _id: new ObjectId("63f16c8903e5a86d748ab2c9"),
      batch: 1,
      department: 'None',
      stream: 'None',
      subject: 'd',
      class: new ObjectId("63efb168503e390f0b7c986a"),
      grades: [Array],
      createdAt: 2023-02-19T00:25:45.106Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-02-19T00:25:45.106Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    sem: 1
    sem: 1
  }
    sem: 1
  }
]
```

the route

```
router.route("/find/grades").post(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { fullName } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ fullName });
    console.log(fullName);
    const grades = await Grade.find({
      department: user.department,
      stream: user.stream,
      batch: user.batch,
      "grades.studentId": user._id,
    });
    const updatedGrades = await Promise.all(
      grades.map(async (gd, i) => {
        console.log(gd.class);
        const sem = await Class.findById({ _id: gd.class });
        return { gd, sem: sem.semester };
      })
    );
    console.log(updatedGrades);
    res.json({ updatedGrades });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Grade.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { UserContext } from "../App.jsx";

function Grade() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [data, setData] = useState([{ gd: {}, sem: 1 }]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user/find/grades", {
          fullName: state.name,
        });
        const newData = res.data.updatedGrades.map((item) => ({ gd: item.gd, sem: item.sem }));
        console.log(newData);
        setData(newData);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="w-full text-center">
      {console.log(data)}
      <table className="table-auto lg:table-fixed w-full">
        <thead>
          <tr className="bg-gray-800 text-white">
            <th className="lg:w-52 px-4 py-2">Batch</th>
            <th className="px-4 py-2">Department</th>
            <th className="px-4 py-2">Stream</th>
            <th className="px-4 py-2">Semester</th>
            <th className="px-4 py-2">Subject</th>
            <th className="px-4 py-2">Grade</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data && data.length > 0 &&
            data.map((item, index) => (
              <tr key={index} className="text-gray-700">
                <td className="border px-2 py-px">{item.gd.batch}</td>
                <td className="text-center border px-0.5 py-px">
                  {item.gd.department}
                </td>
                <td className="border px-1.5 py-px">{item.gd.stream}</td>
                <td className="border px-2 py-px">{item.sem}</td>
                <td className="text-center border px-2 py-px">
                  {item.gd.subject}
                </td>
                <td className="text-center border px-2 py-px">
                  {item.gd?.grades[0]?.grade}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Grade;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that was causing the error is i incorrectly initialize the state ,i should only initialize the state with an array,but i made a mistake by initializing it with an array with a single object and some how cause this issue related to the state update.
Indeed,that has solved my problem completely.
so instead of, `const [data, setData] = useState([{ gd: {}, sem: 1 }]);`
should be   `const [data, setData] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 0):

Can you, please, console log `item.gd.grades`? I have a feeling that that will be an Array of Arrays, meaning it's not `[{ grade: 5 }]` but `[[{ grade: 5 }]]` (note that it is a nested array).

If that would be an array of objects you would see `[Object]` not `[Array]`. To see the full log you can do the following: `console.log(JSON.stringify(thingie, null, 2))` (where `thingie` is what you want to log, `null` is the replacer, `2` - indent, refer to [MDN JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify))

Comment: no no that could not be because in the schema definition i have definded the grades field to  be only an array of objects with keys studentId and grade not an array of array of objects ,the response that i have give above was incorrect some how ,because i checked  it now it gives this

Comment: {"updatedGrades": [
    {"gd": {"_id": "6406037bff2488090f5846bf","batch": 1,"department": "None", "stream": "None", "subject": "b", "class": "63f76c75bf0e6024f930cfe7", "grades": [
          {"studentId": "63f7662dbf0e6024f930cfc7", "grade": "A", "_id": "6406037bff2488090f5846c0"}]},"sem": 1},
    {"gd": {"_id": "6406038eff2488090f5846c4","batch": 1,"department": "None", "stream": "None", "subject": "d", "class": "63f76c75bf0e6024f930cfe7",
 "grades": [{"studentId": "63f7662dbf0e6024f930cfc7", "grade": "C+", "_id": "6406038eff2488090f5846c5"}]},
      "sem": 1
    }
  ]
}

Comment: when i say the server responds with this values in the question above i mean it is the console logs not the actual response by requesting the route ,the response is the above comment i give you. note i have removed some of the text and reduce space since comments have limits on characters